# Testing Mono.delay with StepVerifier

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to test `Mono.delay` using `StepVerifier`.
My code is as follow:

```
Mono[Long] mono = Mono.delay(Duration.ofDays(5));

StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> mono)
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(5))
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .expectComplete()
    .verify();
```

And I'm getting the following stacktrace

```
expectation "expectNextCount" failed (expected: count = 1; actual: counted = 0; signal: onError(reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException:
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable))
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNextCount" failed (expected: count = 1; actual: counted = 0; signal: onError(reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable))
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.failPrefix(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1679)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.fail(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1675)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.checkCountMismatch(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:886)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignalCount(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1112)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:963)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:727)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay.subscribe(MonoDelay.java:59)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:532)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:508)
```

After tracing the source code, it seems that the executors are shutdown on the method `Schedulers.setFactory`

I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I'm getting to the bottom of the issue.

The `StepVerifier` requires `Supplier` and in my case I provided the `Mono[Long]` with the existing `Mono` which has been created.
I should instead doing the following

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofDays(5)))
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(5))
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .expectComplete()
    .verify();
```

This way the `Mono` provided will not be created first and the executor will not be shutdown.

Comment: you're exactly right! the trouble with your initial solution is that the Mono is already created with a real Scheduler before the StepVerifier can set up a virtual time Scheduler